# How to Import the userdefined rules in sonarqube 5.5

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

Currently i am using Sonarqube 5.5 for static code review.I am not able to find any way to import the userdefined javascript rules.

Please let me know if anyone have the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write custom rules for JavaScript in Java by creating your own custom plugin, which would depend on the JavaScript plugin for the basics and provide your extra rules.

For details, [see the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+JavaScript).

Comment: Hi Ann..Thanks for the reply.I am looking for the solution to save the existing java script rules from the sonarqube ,from there just keep some rules and upload again to sonarqube.Please suggest if you have any solution.